# Access 2010 Form won't save record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with some fields on it. Form was created from the table in question.

I've tried to use the button wizard to create a save button, I've tried to use the following:

```
Private Sub saveRecord_Click()
   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End Sub
```

Nothing works, any method I try to save the info doesn't work. I've made sure the form is bound, as far as I can tell it is, it was created off that table.

I have this line when the form loads to make sure the form is on a new record:

```
Me.Recordset.AddNew
```

From my limited understanding of the language, setting the form to a new record and then doing a save command should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` will only do a save if there is something to save.  Simply adding a record to the form's recordset doesn't give you anything to save.

Make this change to `saveRecord_Click()` to confirm whether that is the explanation:

```vb
Private Sub saveRecord_Click()
    If Me.Dirty = True Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    Else
        MsgBox "nothing to save"
    End If
End Sub
```

Some other suggestions ...

Since you want to go to the new record when the form loads, use `GoToRecord` instead of `Me.Recordset.AddNew`:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord Record:=acNewRec
End Sub
```

The version of `saveRecord_Click()` I suggested earlier was only to explore the problem.  But for routine use, it doesn't make sense to allow the user to click a `saveRecord` button and then tell them there is nothing to save.  It is better to only make the button clickable when there is something to save.

So you can disable the command button in the form's `On Current` event and enable it in the `On Dirty` event (which means there is something to save).

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.saveRecord.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.saveRecord.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Also, as the last step of `saveRecord_Click()`, you may wish to `SetFocus` on another control and disable the command button.

Comment: The save click on it's own didn't fix it, but changing the:
    Me.Recordset.AddNew

to your code that you gave me did fix it. Just a quick question, when a record finally went in, the id jumped from 5 to 22, which I guess means the other records were generated but not saved, any idea where those would have sat? Just trying to understand the process.

Comment: Sounds like `id` is autonumber.  When you start to insert a new record, Access retrieves the autonumber seed value and then increments the seed in preparation for the next time the autonumber is used.  But when the current insert is aborted, its reserved autonumber is lost.

Comment: I've implemented your enable/disable buttons and the disable works good, but the enable won't trigger even when I fill out all fields. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the form module include `Option Explicit` in the Declarations section?  And then does the code compile without error?

Comment: It's Option Compare Database, changed it to Explicit to try it, same results. And the code compiles without error yes.

Comment: Can you check whether the code is evaluated at runtime?  Set a break point and step through the code if you know how to do that.  Otherwise add a line, `MsgBox "hi"`, after the line which sets the `Enabled` property ... and find out whether the `MsgBox` is displayed.